# Querying 200k rows of data using IN statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling to query 200k rows of data using a very large IN statement in SQL.

```
select CreatedDate 
from ExchangeAccounts 
where SamAccountName in ('abc','def','ghi',....., until 200k)
```

The server returns an error

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: by not listing 200k values in the `IN`. You could insert them first into a table and query them

Comment: How do you obtain  the  ... in content .?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They're very different products.

Comment: I'd say it's [SQL Server](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28945/query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-and-could-not-produce-a-query-plan#43189), I'll fix tags.

Comment: it mssql server. yes.

Comment: the ... in content i got from excel. the client want to query based in the id. the id is about 200k.

Comment: btw i cannot easily modify the table because of rules. so i can only query the table. not to modify the table.

Comment: no one said that you needed to modify the table, but you could insert the 200k values in another table (or a temp table) and query it

Comment: is there any other option? because i cannot simply add a temp table. theres a log and i cannot do that. sorry about the rules.

Comment: Run your query in smaller parts -- or get the rules changed. No idea why rules would prevent you from creating a temp. table

Comment: 200k in smaller parts? its gonna take times. :(

Comment: I'm not sure why the rules would prevent you from using a temp table.  Are you allowed to use variables?  Create a table variable.

Comment: i think it is allowed.  what is table variable? from what i understand its from stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is to first get all 200,000 strings into a table as rows.  SQL Server can search a second table much more efficiently versus using the IN clause.  Also, you are encountering a limitation due to the length of your IN clause.

If you cannot source the 200,000 strings as a table with 200,000 rows then this function can help - it will generate a table from the comma delimited list:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[uParseCSV2Rows](
  @csv varchar(MAX)
)  
returns @table table(Indexkey int         identity(1, 1) primary key,
                     xValue   varchar(200))
as  
BEGIN
  declare @pos int
  select @csv = nullif(ltrim(rtrim(@csv)), '') + ','
  while 1 = 1 and @csv is not null
  begin
    select @pos = charindex(',', @csv)
    if @pos <= 0 break

    insert @table(xValue)
    select left(@csv, @pos - 1)

    select @csv = substring(@csv, @pos+1, len(@csv))
  end
  return
END
```

Then, you can search like this:

```
select CreatedDate 
from ExchangeAccounts a
where exists (select 1 from dbo.uParseCSV2Rows('abc,def,ghi,...,200k') i where i.xValue = a.SamAccountName)
```

Comment: i got a message error where it says "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'."

Comment: if i use **select CreatedDate 
from ExchangeAccounts** only, it runs perfectly.

Comment: Ismael, I tested the code and it worked ok.  what version of SQL server are you running?

Comment: sql server management studio 2016. is the different version counts?

Comment: @IsmaelBinAzman The syntax of SQL depends on the server, not the client.